# Keyboard and mouse are not working on dell laptop after updrading to 14.04 lts version

Tags: keyboard, mouse, dell, dell-vostro

Need a help,

System Configuration: 
Dell vostro ,
RAM: 4GB ,
Processor: i3 ,
HDD: 500GB ,

Yesterday, I have upgraded my ubuntu OS version 12.** LTS into 14.04 LTS on that time my external mouse and keyboard was working fine. It's a connected via PS2 to USB connector on laptop. After upgrading these stopped working. i have connected another mouse via USB on same usb port and it's working fine.

plz help me to solve this problem...